# How to filter by table-A from table-B (table-A is linked to table-B, not the otherwise)

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset, django-filter

I have the following models:

```
# models.py

class Movement(models.Model):
    class Direction(models.TextChoices):
        SENT = 'S', _('Sent')
        RETURNED = 'R', _('Returned')

    case = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=False, null=False, blank=False, db_index=True, db_column='case_id')
    direction = models.CharField(unique=False, null=False, blank=False, db_index=False, max_length=1, choices=Direction.choices, default=Direction.SENT, db_column='direction')
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, db_index=True, default=current_date, db_column='date')


class Case(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['number', 'year', 'kind', 'police_station'], name='unique_case2')]

    class Kind(models.TextChoices):
        MISDEMEANOR = 'M', _('Misdemeanor')
        TRAFFIC = 'T', _('Traffic')

    police_station = models.ForeignKey(PoliceStation, on_delete=models.PROTECT, unique=False, null=False, blank=False, db_index=True, db_column='police_station_id')
    name = models.CharField(unique=False, null=False, blank=False, db_index=True, default='', max_length=100, db_column='name')
    number = models.SmallIntegerField(unique=False, null=False, blank=False, db_index=True, db_column='number')
    year = models.SmallIntegerField(unique=False, null=False, blank=False, db_index=True, default=current_year, db_column='year')
    kind = models.CharField(unique=False, null=False, blank=False, db_index=False, max_length=1, choices=Kind.choices, default=Kind.MISDEMEANOR, db_column='kind')
    registered_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, db_index=True, default=current_datetime, db_column='registered_at')
```

Some facts about the Movement table:

- The Movement table may have multiple records for the same case.
- The `direction` field can not have the same value for two records in a row. (ex: if the last Movement record for `case_id = 2` is the `direction = 'S'`, the next movement must be `direction = 'R'`).

And I would like to filter cases by their last movement's directions from `CaseAdmin` class, into three types:

1. Sent.
2. Returned.
3. Has no movement yet.

Now how to build a query to filter cases by their last movement?

Filter rules:

- Only the last movement record should be considered.
- Last movement record should be determined by its `-date` not `id`.
- The 'Sent' option, must show the available cases in which their last Movement `direction = 'S'`.
- The 'Returned' option, must show the available cases in which their last Movement `direction = 'R'`.
- 'Has no movement yet' option, must show the available cases in which they have no Movement records yet.

I thought about it, and I came up with two solutions:

1. Add an extra boolean field called `is_latest` to the Movement table, in order to know which record is to be considered as the latest movement when building the query.
   Which needs two update statements for the Movement table whenever each new movement record is added for the same case.
2. Or, add an extra foreign key field called `last_movement` to the Case table that points to the latest movement record in the Movement table.
   I think this one is better since it needs only one update statement for the Case table whenever each new movement record is added for the same case.

Both solutions need to be maintained when each new movement record is got inserted into the Movement table.

But I was wondering if there is another good / better / practical solution for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to define extra `ForeignKey`s or add extra fields to the `Movement` table. We can work with a [**`Subquery`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery


class CaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
            .annotate(
                last_direction=Subquery(
                    Movement.objects.filter(case_id=OuterRef('pk'))
                    .order_by('-date')
                    .values('direction')[:1]
                )
            )
        )

    list_filter = [LastDirectionFilter]
```

with as `LastDirectionFilter`:

```
from django.contrib import admin


class LastDirectionFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'Last direction'
    parameter_name = 'last_direction'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return [
            ('S', 'Sent'),
            ('R', 'Returned'),
            ('-', 'No movement yet'),
        ]

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        value = self.value()
        if value == '-':
            return queryset.filter(last_direction=None)
        elif value is not None:
            return queryset.filter(last_direction=value)
        return queryset
```

here we thus filter on our annotation that can be `None` if there is no movement yet, or `'S'` or `'R'`.